# more navigating the dom help

Tags: jquery

I'm currently in the sumMe row, how do I access the block1a updateMe class with JQuery?

```
<div class='headerBlock'>

  <div class='block1'>
            <div class='block1a'>
                        <label class='updateMe'> </label>
            </div>
  </div>

  <div class='block2'>
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$1.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>          
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$2.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector will do it.

```
$(".block1a .updateMe")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(.....).closest('.headerBlock').find('.updateMe');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.block1a .updateMe').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".block1a label.updateMe")` will give you the required element.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the element using `.closest()` or `.parents()` to get up to `<div class='headerBlock'>` then find the `<label class="updateMe">` but you're likely better off just selecting it on it's own (and based on [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/get-leaf-node-from-separate-branch-of-a-different-leaf) it is faster to use a new selector vs trying to find it starting at one of the `.sumMe` elements)

here's a possible approach if I'm guessing right on what you're trying to do:

```
var $updateMe = $('.block1a .updateMe'), // or just $('.updateMe') if there are no others with that class
    $sumMe = $('.sumMe'),
    sum = 0;

$sumMe.each(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    sum += someConvertToFloatFunction($that.text());
});

$updateMe.text(someConvertToDollarFormatFunction(sum));
```

**UPDATED**

if there are multiple `.headerBlock` elements you can use the above wrapped in a `.each` function for the `.headerBlock`s and use the current `.headerBlock` as a context for the selectors.

```
$('.headerBlock').each(function() {
    var $that = $(this),
        $updateMe = $('.block1a .updateMe', $that), // use $that as a context for the selector
        $sumMe = $('.sumMe', $that), // use $that as a context for the selector
        sum = 0;

    $sumMe.each(function() {
        sum += someConvertToFloatFunction($(this).text());
    });

    $updateMe.text(someConvertToDollarFormatFunction(sum));
});
```

if you're summing the `.sumMe` elements (in a given `.headerBlock`) as a **one-off**, then probably using `.closest()` as mentioned in @Ariel's answer is a good way to go.

Comment: what if there are multiple ".headerBlock"?

Comment: @rod, I've updated my answer for multiple `.headerBlock` elements